# Put Nginx in front of Heroku app to deny access to it by IP

Tags: nginx, heroku

We have Heroku app on `http://random-heroku-app.herokuapp.com` and access to it(using HTTPS) must be limited to just 2 IPs. Nginx with it's allow function is perfect here.

But is it possible to deploy Nginx in AWS and configure it so that it would be "in front" of Heroku app?

***Example:***
If I go to `http://random-heroku-app.herokuapp.com`, Nginx firstly is going to check if I am trying to connect from allowed IP and only then, proxy me to `http://random-heroku-app.herokuapp.com`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you using https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx? The ip `allow` and `deny` don't work for me at all.

Comment: one does realize this is security through obscurity? random-heroku-app.herokuapp.com is going to be 24/7 publicly facing. All one needs to do is hit heroku's proxies with a dictionary attack and they would have found your application.

Better to ensure your app/api can be accessed only with a valid saml/jwt/oauth token then put it behind cloudflare where one has a full waf, cdn, logging, and firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing!

You'll just need a server block inside of nginx, that would look something like that:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name random-heroku-app.herokuapp.com;
    ssl_certificate .ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key .ssl/key.key;

    allow   publicip;
    deny    all;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://appip:443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out soon and will get back to you with answer.

Comment: So I've checked the current config and it's not working. Does certificates are mandatory for this(they are on the other herokuapp server and I don't know how to retrieve them)?

Comment: They are. You nginx frontend is the one that establishes https connection.
What error do you receive?

Comment: Don't receive any. I've used my AWS EC2 which have Nginx installed and just added new file in site-available(made a symlink in sites enabled too) with your proposed configurations. Nginx restarts. I guess I need to retrieve certs from Heroku app server?

Comment: Did you forward your domain name to your new nginx-instance?

Comment: Am I able to forward `herokuapp` domain(not owned by me) name to my AWS instance?

Comment: No idea. You can check whether or not it's working by adding IP and domain in your local 'hosts' file. 

If it does work, you could use a different domain name for your needs:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains